# How to Sign-in Gmail using Selenium automation testing in Java? Now that they block sign in from testing browser driver. Is there a way?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

How to Sign-in Gmail using Selenium automation testing in Java? Now that they block sign-in from testing browser driver. Is there a way?

Comment: Not only Java, Python has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use Gmail API to integrate Gmail with any automation than going for automating the Gmail UI.